# how to add permission control in laravel with vue project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm adding vue js into my current laravel apps so i can make it SPA and thats mean laravel is only acting as backend and rest of it is controlled by vue js from rendering view to routing.

My current laravel apps using [kodeine laravel-acl](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl) for controlling which page and which action that my user can do by simply

put this in route:

```
Route::get('admin', [
        'as'           => 'admins.admin.index',           
        'uses'         => 'UserController@index',
        'middleware'   => ['auth', 'acl'],
        'can'          => 'view.admin_view']);
```

and if i just do this in view to hide some action if user don't have permission

```
@permission('view.admin_view')
   //some link or button          
@endpermission
```

and all these permission is stored in mysql database and each user have different set of permission.

but how to do that if i making it vue js SPA? since all route is controlled via vue js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform checks before going to a certain route via `beforeEnter()` in routeConfig. Sample is here:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ... Do your checkings here
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply permission detection logic you can use CASL - https://github.com/stalniy/casl

There are a lot of interesting stuff in documentation and articles on medium explaining how integrate with Vue and other popular frameworks!

Comment: how to integrating it to laravel-mysql? i find only integration for mongoDB

Comment: To do integration with laravel and MySQL you need to port CASL to PHP. It’s written in JavaScript

Comment: @LaurensiusTony also you can add additional properties in your policies and gates in order to be able to define conditions. Without conditions it should be quite easy to use. I plan to publish an article about this soon